# Postgres: how many rows are subsets of the list in the current row?

Tags: postgresql

I had a hard time formulating the title of this question, but basically I want to find out how many rows are subsets of the list in the current row.  An example should make it clear:

```
CREATE TABLE t (
    elements integer[] NOT NULL
);
INSERT INTO t(elements)
VALUES
('{1}'),
('{1}'),
('{2}'),
('{3}'),
('{1,2}'),
('{1,2}'),
('{2,3}');
```

Now, the answer I'm looking for should be

```
+------------+----------+
| elements   | covers   |
|------------+----------|
| [1]        | 2        | [1], [1]
| [1]        | 2        | [1], [1]
| [2]        | 1        | [2]
| [3]        | 1        | [3]
| [1, 2]     | 5        | [1], [1], [2], [1, 2], [1, 2]
| [1, 2]     | 5        | [1], [1], [2], [1, 2], [1, 2]
| [2, 3]     | 3        | [2], [3], [2, 3]
+------------+----------+
```

I guess this should be done with the <@ or @> operators. **Is this possible to do with a window function? Or how else would I most easily do it?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think a window function helps here. I'd just do a subquery:

```
SELECT
  t_out.elements,
  (SELECT count(*) FROM t t_in WHERE t_in.elements <@ t_out.elements) AS covers
FROM t t_out;
```

<sup>(With `json_agg` instead of `count` you can see which ones were covered.)</sup>

Comment: Thanks, that works well. But I needed to rename inner and outer to t1 and t2, otherwise I get syntax errors (I believed inner and outer are reserved keywords in postgres)

Comment: @rutchkiwi oops, of course they are. fixed, thanks!